# Footnote formatting with bigfoot para style

Tags: footnotes, bigfoot

Can I control when the bigfoot para style breaks the line? This demonstrates the problem:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage{bigfoot}
  \DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default}
  \textheight=2in

  \begin{document}
  Can I\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
  make the second note stay on the same line as the first,\footnote{Short.}
  instead of coming down to the third\footnote{This one.} and the fourth\footnote{Hello.}?

  \end{document}
```

[image]